# Flutter populate dropdown button from firestore array

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I populate this array list into a dropdown button?

I want to populate this list of the location to the dropdown button.
[here is how my database looks like]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5yDh.png

Comment: checkout this link https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter populate dropdown button from json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57847707/flutter-populate-dropdown-button-from-json-array)

Comment: when I tried manually it's working. when I use data['location']. its give me a error.'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>'

Answer (score 3):

I know, it's too late to answer your question. But maybe, mine is for anybody who seeks an answer.

Just use streambuilder to stream firestore data in your dropdown.
Here is my example:

```
      StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('your collectionName').document('yourDocument').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return textCustom('Loading', Colors.black87, 16, 'Montserrat');
        } else {
          final data = snapshot.data['data'];
          return Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              canvasColor: Color(0xFF221F1F),
            ),
            child: DropdownButtonFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),                                               
              value: _value,
              items: data
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                    (x) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: textCustom(
                          x, Colors.white, 16, 'Montserrat'),
                      value: '${x}',
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
             
              onChanged: (val) => setState(() {
                _value = val;
           
              }),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the `flutter_form_bloc` package. It's very helpful and you can asynchronously add items to a dropdown array so you can fetch them from an API or for your needs, Firebase.

If you do not want to use a package however, you could create an empty list and assign it to the items parameter initially. In your `initState` method, you could then populate that list with items and then call `setState`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way, but gets the work done.
Create a temporary list, then use that list to do a for each.

```
tempList = returnedDoc['location'];
tempList.forEach((element) {
   Locations.add(element);
}),
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a dropdown button in following way.

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String dropdownValue;
  List<String> listOfStrings = ["apple", "banana", "strawberry", "cherry"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: dropdownValue,
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          iconSize: 24,
          elevation: 16,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
          underline: Container(
            height: 2,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          ),
          onChanged: (String newValue) {
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = newValue;
            });
          },
          items: listOfStrings.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>

Comment: like that it's working. I'm trying to use this its gives error. List<String> listOfStrings = data['location']

Comment: what is data['location'] ? you have to give List<String>.

Comment: data['location'] is the data I'm receiving from firestore. you might get idea after seeing this image. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5yDh.png)

Comment: use as following.  List<String> listOfStrings = data['location'].map((e) => e.toString()).toList(); @Leewan

Comment: List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String> still getting same error.

Comment: it should work for you can you add how you are using it ?

Comment: Still, it did not work out for me. here my full code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFfNb.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/luUDO.png @Viren V Varasadiya